# Powershell to find the principal/mirror in SQL servers

Tags: sql, t-sql, powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to know if a instance of sql server is in mirror/prinicipal by running any sql query? and secondly i want to run this on say 60-80 instances everyday at 4am automatically possible? I would like to use powershell used it before quite easy to use from experience. Tks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You will need to play around with SMO objects.

```
$server = "dwhtest-new"
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $server
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$dbs = $srv.Databases
    foreach ($db1 in $dbs)
            {
                $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database 
                $db = $db1
                $DatabaseName = $db.Name
                Write-Host $DatabaseName
                Write-Host "MirroringStatus:" $db.MirroringStatus
                Write-Host "DBState:"  $db.Status
                Write-Host
            }
```

If your DB's mirroring is still intact you will recieve  'Synchronized' for MirroringStatus and its its the Primary it will say "Normal" for the status and if its the failover it will say "Restoring". Unfortunately there is no way, that im aware of, to just pull out the status of "Mirror" or "principle". You will jsut have to build logic to check both fo those values.
Restoring

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you going to setup the job?

If you want to run it from one central server that collects all the information then SMO would be the way to go with PowerShell. The answer provided by [KickerCost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254217/847990) can work but would need some more work to be able to run it for multiple servers. It would be best to take his example and turn it into a working function that will allow the server names to be piped in.

If you are going to just run a job locally on each server (scheduled task or SQL Agent job) that may point to the script on a network share, then maybe output that info to a file (like servername_instance.log) you can use a one-liner with SQLPS:

```
dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\KRINGER\Default\Databases | Select Name, MirroringStatus
```

KRINGER is my server name, with a default instance. If you have named instances then replace the "default" with the instance name.
Your output from this command would be similar to this:

```
Name                     MirroringStatus
----                     ---------------
AdventureWorks           None
AdventureWorksDW         None
```

Obviously I don't have any databases involved in mirroring.